# How do I debug a create-react-app on AWS Amplify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I'm following the tutorial on AWS Amplify to deploy a simple create-react-app. No code added to the initial boiler plate. However when I deploy the app and check the Url i see a:

This main.d1m8xst4r8xkbi.amplifyapp.com page can’t be found

Any clues on how i can proceed?

edit this was the build file:

```
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    # IMPORTANT - Please verify your build commands
    build:
      commands: []
  artifacts:
    # IMPORTANT - Please verify your build output directory
    baseDirectory: /
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths: []
```

edit2 The command is "react-scripts build" and the build folder should share a directory with the package.json so I tried modifying the commands and files as follows:

```
build:
  commands: 
   - "react-scripts build"
 ....
files:
  - "build"
```

and it now throws a build error. I think I'm missing something and my syntax is off (sorry first time doing this!)
If I look at the build log for this error it shows:

```
2021-03-28T17:22:49.752Z [INFO]: ## Starting Frontend Build
                                 # Starting phase: build
                                 # Executing command: react-scripts build
```

edit3, i tried this:

```
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    # IMPORTANT - Please verify your build commands
    build:
      commands: "react-scripts build"
  artifacts:
    # IMPORTANT - Please verify your build output directory
    baseDirectory: "/build"
    files: 
  cache:
    paths: []
```

and got this in the logs:

```
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    # IMPORTANT - Please verify your build commands
    build:
      commands: "react-scripts build"
  artifacts:
    # IMPORTANT - Please verify your build output directory
    baseDirectory: "/build"
    files: 
  cache:
    paths: []
```

edit:
I've tried different things, including copying verbatim screenshots from the AWS amplify "hello world" tutorial. It's not working. I'm very confused as this is my first time deploying. Help is appreciated and encouraging!

---

edit, here is the build log from your suggestion:

```
                                 # Starting phase: preBuild
                                 # Executing command: npm install
2021-04-03T10:30:06.970Z [WARNING]: npm
2021-04-03T10:30:06.970Z [WARNING]: WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/codebuild/output/src437022859/src/L34-1/package.json'
2021-04-03T10:30:06.974Z [WARNING]: npm
2021-04-03T10:30:06.974Z [WARNING]: notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
2021-04-03T10:30:06.976Z [WARNING]: npm
2021-04-03T10:30:06.976Z [WARNING]: WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/codebuild/output/src437022859/src/L34-1/package.json'
2021-04-03T10:30:06.980Z [WARNING]: npm
2021-04-03T10:30:06.980Z [WARNING]: WARN L34-1 No description
2021-04-03T10:30:06.984Z [WARNING]: npm
2021-04-03T10:30:06.984Z [WARNING]: WARN L34-1 No repository field.
2021-04-03T10:30:06.988Z [WARNING]: npm
2021-04-03T10:30:06.988Z [WARNING]: WARN L34-1 No README data
2021-04-03T10:30:06.992Z [WARNING]: npm
2021-04-03T10:30:06.992Z [WARNING]: WARN L34-1 No license field.
2021-04-03T10:30:06.992Z [WARNING]: 
2021-04-03T10:30:07.239Z [INFO]: up to date in 0.365s
2021-04-03T10:30:07.239Z [INFO]: found 0 vulnerabilities
2021-04-03T10:30:07.323Z [INFO]: # Completed phase: preBuild
                                 # Starting phase: build
2021-04-03T10:30:07.324Z [INFO]: # Executing command: npm run build
2021-04-03T10:30:07.471Z [WARNING]: npm
2021-04-03T10:30:07.471Z [WARNING]: ERR! code ENOENT
                                    npm ERR! syscall open
                                    npm ERR! path /codebuild/output/src437022859/src/L34-1/package.json
                                    npm ERR! errno -2
2021-04-03T10:30:07.472Z [WARNING]: npm
2021-04-03T10:30:07.473Z [WARNING]: ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/codebuild/output/src437022859/src/L34-1/package.json'
                                    npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
                                    npm ERR! enoent
2021-04-03T10:30:07.479Z [WARNING]: 
2021-04-03T10:30:07.479Z [WARNING]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
                                    npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-04-03T10_30_07_473Z-debug.log
2021-04-03T10:30:07.479Z [HELP]: Outputting the npm debug log
                                 0 info it worked if it ends with ok
                                 1 verbose cli [
                                 1 verbose cli   '/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.21.0/bin/node',
                                 1 verbose cli   '/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.21.0/bin/npm',
                                 1 verbose cli   'run',
                                 1 verbose cli   'build'
                                 1 verbose cli ]
                                 2 info using npm@6.14.11
                                 3 info using node@v12.21.0
                                 4 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/codebuild/output/src437022859/src/L34-1/package.json'
                                 5 verbose cwd /codebuild/output/src437022859/src/L34-1
                                 6 verbose Linux 4.14.219-119.340.amzn1.x86_64
                                 7 verbose argv "/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.21.0/bin/node" "/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.21.0/bin/npm" "run" "build"
                                 8 verbose node v12.21.0
                                 9 verbose npm  v6.14.11
                                 10 error code ENOENT
                                 11 error syscall open
                                 12 error path /codebuild/output/src437022859/src/L34-1/package.json
                                 13 error errno -2
                                 14 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/codebuild/output/src437022859/src/L34-1/package.json'
                                 15 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
                                 16 verbose exit [ -2, true ]
2021-04-03T10:30:07.482Z [ERROR]: !!! Build failed
2021-04-03T10:30:07.482Z [ERROR]: !!! Non-Zero Exit Code detected
2021-04-03T10:30:07.482Z [INFO]: # Starting environment caching...
2021-04-03T10:30:07.482Z [INFO]: # Environment caching completed
Terminating logging...
```

Comment: What do you see in aws amplify console? All 4 stages completed successfully (provision, build, deploy & verify) ?

Comment: Yes have a green checkmark next to all of them.

Comment: Ok. In that case can you have a look into the build settings (App settings>Build settings) configuration and update it to the question

Comment: Ok i added it and i can see the problem, but i'm not sure what goes where exactly

Comment: I'm not sure if adding the - is correct. I'm reading their specification but not sure where I am going wrong. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/build-settings.html#yml-specification-syntax

Answer (score 0):

I know maybe is obvious, but before deploy do you generated the build files? If not, you need to use this command below:

```
npm run build
```

Comment: In my package.json i have it as:

"build": "react-scripts build"

Answer (score 0):

Update your build setting as below in the Apps build settings in the AWS console.

```
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm install
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run build
  artifacts:
    # IMPORTANT - Please verify your build output directory
    baseDirectory: build
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

Once the build settings are updated, we need to add URL redirect's for React SPA under "Redirects and rewrites" in app settings.

Source Address:

```
</^[^.]+$|\.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf|map|json)$)([^.]+$)/>
```

Target Address:

```
/index.html
```

Read more here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/redirects.html#redirects-for-single-page-web-apps-spa

Comment: sorry to bother you again, but your suggestion didn't work :/ I've included the build log in the last edit of my post.